# What is that BNC-like connectors on ZTE MF825 LTE modem?

Tags: connector, antenna

What is that BNC-like connectors on ZTE MF825 LTE modem?

[image]

There are two of such connectors on the device. The diameter is approx of 3 mm.

I understand that this is for antenna, but what is the name of connector?

**UPDATE**

Connector is a cylinder, covered with metal from outside and filled with insulator from inside, having small hole in the center. The outer diameter is approx 3 mm.

Comment: Could you provide a better photo? Like, focus the connector and not the background label.

Comment: I agree with you criticism about focusing, but with better focusing the picture won't contain more information. So, since this is not art community I will leave photo as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a [TS-9](http://www.smk.co.jp/page.jsp?id=3849&version=en) connector for an external antenna. Check the dimensions with a pair of calipers and compare with the part drawing.

Comment: the diameter is 3 mm approx, measured with calipers, but it was hard to get inside small room under cover, so the value is approximal

Answer (score 1):

External antenna, almost certainly. I have a similar cellular modem and I've read the manual of mine :-)

Antennas for these are rather rare/hard to find (yet). Here's a close up for the plug that's supposed to go in there.

[image]

It's from that famous Chines auction site... and is the only close-up image I found for the male connector, which probably says how widespread they are[n't].

Here's a video of a desperate Ukrainian who replaced his with a more common (bigger one): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAMT0xyNIzE

As Spehro Pefhany says, the tiny one is called TS-9, although few people know that... I couldn't remember it. "cellular modem external antenna" will likely give you more useful ready-made products. Some LTE antenna sellers e.g. [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006FRAPFW) don't even mention the type of connector... even they probably don't know what it's called.